# jsf-2.2: f:view contracts attribute found, but not used at top level

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, contracts

Hello I am getting the following in the server console everytime I enter on a webpage:`f:view contracts attribute found, but not used at top level`.

I am using jsf template and I have a default.xhtml template file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ...xmlns...>
<f:view contracts="default" locale="#{bbClevcore.locale}">
  <h:head>
    ...
  </h:head>
  <h:body id="body">
    <header>
      ...
    </header>

    <section>
      <h:panelGroup layout="block">
        <h:panelGroup id="section" layout="block">
          <ui:insert name="section" />
        </h:panelGroup>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </section>

    <footer>
      ...
    </footer>
    </ui:insert>

  </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

I have the following contract directory:

-src/main/webapp/contracts/default/common/css/main.css

And in the actual page: index.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/components"
    template="/templates/default.xhtml">
    ...
    <ui:define name="section">
       ....
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The contract works since when I change contracts value from *default* to let say *alternative* , having another main.css in an alternative folder, the page takes the change and shows the alternative style. Am I using f:view in the right location?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set contract in global template. JSF allows to
set it in a first requested file (Template-Client) only. Try this!

Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ...xmlns...>
  <h:head>
    ...
  </h:head>

  <h:body id="body">
    <header>
      ...
    </header>

    <section>
      <h:panelGroup layout="block">
        <h:panelGroup id="section" layout="block">
          <ui:insert name="section" />
        </h:panelGroup>
      </h:panelGroup>
    </section>

    <footer>
      ...
    </footer>

  </h:body>
</html>
```

Template-Client:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

    <f:view contracts="alternative">
        <ui:composition template="/templates/default.xhtml">
            ...
            <ui:define name="section">
               ....
            </ui:define>
            ...
        </ui:composition>
    </f:view>

</ui:composition>
```